# NodeJS - use package and it's dependencies from local system

Tags: node.js, npm

I am facing a problem connecting to NodeJS due to proxy that is installed in my org. I am working with the infra team, but we are not able to fix the issue.

So for the time being, to make sure I am not blocked, I was hoping if there is a way by which I can refer to the projects which are in my local, without hitting the npm registry?

I've 3 modules, A,B,C with the following dependencies:
A depends on B and other libraries
B depends on C and other libraries
C depends on libraries

With help of a colleague, I've been able to get node_modules folder for C, and hence am able to build C now. Using a previous answer, I've linked C to global npm module by using npm link command.

Problem is coming when I am trying to install C in B. As B tries to hit npm registry to install dependencies of C. Is there a way to make B point to the node_modules folder in C to fix the issue?

Will greatly appreciate any help that I can get on this.

Comment: Did you try `npm i --prefer-offline`?

Comment: @Xaqron Thanks for the input. I will try that and update you.

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't work. :(

Comment: Then you may benefit from a local npm like [this one](https://github.com/local-npm/local-npm). Also your company can use its own registry over LAN using [Verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio).

Comment: @Xaqron Yeah, I was checking that. It will definitely help to have a local NPM server if we cannot reach the remote one.